# nginx reverse proxy cookie forwarding

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, heroku

i have 3 heroku apps

1. frontend *react*
2. backend *node*
3. reverse-proxy *nginx*

---

1. calls to reverse-proxy/api/?(.*) are frowarded to backend
2. rest all calls to reverse-proxy are forwarded to frontend

---

the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` code

```
upstream frontend {
    server $FRONTEND_URL;
}

upstream backend {
    server $BACKEND_URL;
}

server {
    listen $PORT;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $FRONTEND_URL;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $BACKEND_URL;
    }

}
```

---

**issue**

i am using cookie for authentication but the cookie being set by backend is not being 'forwarded'

[**my code**](https://github.com/shameekagarwal/gql)

---

**now it works, changes i made**:

1. changing to `secure: false` in my [node app](https://github.com/shameekagarwal/gql/blob/main/backend/src/redis-config.ts) did it for me (will add tls certificate later maybe)
2. suggested fix by @mariolu

now it looks like

```
location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $BACKEND_URL;
    proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
}
```

3. `app.set("trust proxy", true);`

Comment: Personally, I found that on a same origin case scenario, secure can be left `true` but `SameSite` cookies setting must be on `Lax`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need add

```
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
```

in location config.
Variable $http_cookie is user request cookie.